# ASA configuration using packet tracer

Tags: networking, cisco, vlan, asa

I an trying to configure below network.

I am not able to open http://142.12.56.68 from public laptop.

I am able to ping to firewall 192.158.99.1 from VLAN20 laptop0.

I have below configurations on asa and multi switch.
Please let me know what else I need to do perform to complete this network.

```
ciscoasa(config)#show run
: Saved
:
ASA Version 9.6(1)
!
hostname ciscoasa
names
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.99.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 nameif dmz
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0
 ospf authentication message-digest
 ospf message-digest-key 1 md5 *****
!
!
interface Management1/1
 management-only
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 148.12.56.67 255.255.255.0
 ospf authentication message-digest
 ospf message-digest-key 1 md5 *****
!
webvpn
 enable outside
object network DMZ
 subnet 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0
object network LAN
 subnet 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
object network webserver
 host 172.16.1.10
object network webserver-external-ip
 host 148.12.56.68
!
route outside 192.168.99.0 255.255.255.252 148.12.56.68 1
!
access-list OUTSIDE extended permit icmp any any echo-reply
access-list OUTSIDE extended permit icmp any any unreachable
access-list OUTSIDE extended permit tcp any object webserver eq www
access-list OUTSIDE extended permit tcp any host 148.12.56.68 eq www
access-list outside extended permit icmp any any echo-reply
access-list outside extended permit icmp any any unreachable
!
!
access-group OUTSIDE in interface outside
object network DMZ
 nat (dmz,outside) dynamic interface
object network LAN
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network webserver
 nat (dmz,outside) static 148.12.56.68
!
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect icmp 
!
service-policy global_policy global
!
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
!
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0
 network 192.168.99.0 255.255.255.252 area 0
 network 148.12.56.0 255.255.255.0 area 0
 network 171.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 area 1
 network 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 area 1
!
```

For MultiSwitch I have below:

```
> S1#show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1840 bytes
!
version 12.2(37)SE1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname S1
!
ip routing
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
 no switchport
 ip address 192.168.99.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan10
 mac-address 000c.8551.6601
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan20
 mac-address 000c.8551.6602
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 192.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 area 0
 network 172.16.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 1
end
```

` [Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlupn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Management interface in management-only mode, therefore you can only use this interface to manage ASA. As I know you cannot remove management-only option from management interface.

packet tracer command example:

```
packet-tracer input outside tcp <laptop_ip> 148.12.56.68 80
```

At the end of the output you can see **Action** line which show the final action. The next line will show you the reason if the action is **drop**.

You can also check ASA log entries. You should always configure logging feature!!!
Minimal logging configuration:

```
logging enable
logging timestamp
logging buffered informational
logging buffer-size 16384
```

The above configuration will add timestamp to all log messages, log severity level is informational and buffer 16M of log messages.

For more information about ASA logging: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa96/configuration/general/asa-96-general-config/monitor-syslog.html

You can find more information about log severity levels: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Severity_level

To send log messages to a central log server:

```
logging host <asa_interface> <remote_log_server_ip> <protocol/port/>
```

Example, the log messages will be sent from **inside** interface, to **192.168.1.1** remote server to **udp/514** port (standard/legacy syslog protocol and port):

```
logging host inside 192.168.1.1 udp
```

**I think log messages is one of your best friend for troubleshooting!**

Comment: I changed my management interface from firewall to GigabitEthernet.
I tried below command on as to show trace:
192.168.20.3  is IP addtess of laptop 0
packet-tracer input outside tcp 192.168.20.3 148.12.56.68 80

But it says invalid command.

Comment: The packet-tracer command can be used in privileged EXEC mode, so you must run ```enable``` command before ```packet-tracer``` command.

Comment: By the way, I thought public laptop's IP address, not internal one.

Comment: Ohh Ok I think I misunderstood it  This is my first network in packet tracer. Wanted to learn ASA firewall
I will check it with public laptop.
Thank you

Comment: I tried below command in executive mode on asa, but still says invalid command:

ciscoasa#packet-tracer input outside tcp 172.16.1.100 148.12.56.68 80
          ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
 
ciscoasa#

Comment: ^ sign show you where is the problem. As I understood you have changed configuration. Do you have interface which name is outside?

Comment: I think I find the problem. Sorry for the typo. The right command is ```packet-tracer input outside tcp 172.16.1.100 1234 148.12.56.68 80```. I forgot to add source TCP port.

Comment: I recommend to use Cisco documentations. You can download and read online without registration.